# Client cookie not stored properly in redis store using express in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, redis, session-cookies

I have developing one app using express and node.js with redis as session store. First I will show you my code.

```
var express = require('express'),
    redis = require('redis'),

    var app = express();

    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: secret, key: 'express.sid', store: new RedisStore({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 }), cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 } })); 
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

This is working fine for me, But when I see my request header in browser, It is showing cookie value as follows.

```
Cookie:express.sid=s%3AmF_egbthwH9xtg6E3ts9HHLn.l9zuDq1IcApdTUwIP96vpRSTiDLA99iQS2T4HVpV0tE
```

But when I check in redis using redis-cli is is just showing me half of the key under "sess:" key like as follows.

```
sess:mF_egbthwH9xtg6E3ts9HHLn
```

Is it any problem/mistake from my end?

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding '.' (dot) before setting the cookie. It should work. There are certain characters which you can not use in the cookie value.

Comment: thanks @adi, but I don't understand your answer clearly. Where I have to add '.'(dot)?

Comment: in your cookie, there is a period in the value. please replace that with %2E and set the cookie. it should work.